# apache camel time out logic for route without killing the existing job

Tags: apache-camel

I have route which calls multiple services and returns reply.
i want logic where i can give a timeout to a route after that time out it sends a default message along with continuing the existing process.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [camel-bam](http://camel.apache.org/bam.html) (business activity monitoring)...

it allows you to specify business requirement rules like this.

see this unit test for an example:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-bam/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/bam/BamRouteTest.java